# How to change the title that Google shows my blog made with Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, google-search, github-pages

I have a blog made with Jekyll and hosted in Github. When i search any post of my blog in google, Google show the title as:[post name]-[username].

I want see like this: [post name]

I tried change the title of head.html of:

```
  <title>{% if page.title %}{{ page.title }}{% else %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}</title>
```

to

```
<title>{{ page.title }}</title>
```

But still show the title as: [post name]-[username]

Its posible change the title that Google show me with configurations of jekyll ???

Comment: A repository url can help.

Comment: Once you have rebuilt your blog you will need to wait for Google to reindex your site for Google to display the changes.